# Symfony 4 working with locale

Tags: redirect, routes, localization, symfony4

I am trying to learn symfony 4 on a small personal project. But i am have some workaround with `_locale`.

I have a index route like this :

```
# /config/route.yaml
index:
  path: /{_locale}
  controller: App\Controller\IndexController::index
  requirements:
    _locale: '%app.locales%'
  defaults:
    path: /fr
```

And a service setting, containing default locale and parameters :

```
# /config/service.yaml
parameters:
    locale: fr
    app.locales: fr|en
```

with a `translation.yml` file containing the `default_locale` set to `fr`. I am trying to work only with `fr|en`.

```
# /config/package/translation.yaml
framework:
    default_locale: fr
    translator:
        paths:
            - '%kernel.project_dir%/translations'
        fallbacks:
            - '%locale%'
```

My point is, when I hardcode the url `/fr`, everything works well. But, there is no redirection to the `default_locale` when the `{_locale}`is not set in url. In this case, the symfony core profiler throw an error :

`No route found for "GET /%7B_locale%7D"`

Maybe there is something I dont really understand, but if a `default_locale` is set, it has to work as a fallback for the `_locale` parameter, isn't it ?

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1):

In your example you have a route `/{_locale}` and you always have to set `{_locale}` there because of `requirements` section. You get an error `No route found` because Symfony doesn't know that routes `/` and `/{_locale}` are the same and `{_locale}` may be empty. You have to set up the new route `/` and set up the redirect to `/fr` like this:

```
home:
  path: /
  controller: Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\RedirectController::redirectAction
  defaults:
    path: /fr
    permanent: true
```

You can find more info about redirects here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing/redirect_in_config.html